# New paragraph alignment style

Tags: vba, ms-word, paragraph

As you know, Word offers several paragraph alignment options.
When aligning a paragraph to both sides, (CTRL+J), all lines (except the last) are attached to the left and right margins. The last line remains aligned to one side, (usually, according to the direction of the writing and the language).
I want to build a macro that will enable a new paragraph alignment style, like this:
All lines will be aligned to both sides, including the last line, if it has more than one word.
To do this, I want to build code that will increase the font size of " " (the space) by half a point, along the last line only, as long as the last line does not wrap to a new line.
Thanks for the ideas.

The model I was thinking about (and stuck with...) refers to the following conditions:
The cursor is already on the last line.
The code will count the number of spaces to increase,
will increase them by half a point each time.
It will count the number of spaces in the current row - if they are less than the previous count - a one-time reduction will be performed.
By the way, I tried again and again to use https://chat.openai.com/ - and I didn't succeed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not something that can be part of a Word style. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm It is something that might be accomplished without macros in Publisher or another desktop publishing program.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: This is the paragraph design model I want: all lines (except the last) are aligned to both sides, and the last - to the center.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0B0Q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the **CTRL+Shift+J** is just what you were thinking about?

[image]

## 20230616 updated

```vb
Sub New_paragraph_alignment_style_Aligned_to_both_sides_and_the_last_to_the_center()
    Dim p As paragraph, ur As UndoRecord, lns As Lines, ln As Line, recs As Rectangles, rec As Rectangle
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "New_paragraph_alignment_style_Aligned_to_both_sides_and_the_last_to_the_center"
    For Each p In Selection.Paragraphs
        'Set p = Selection.Paragraphs(1)
        With p.Range
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphDistribute
            Set recs = .Document.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)).Rectangles
            For Each rec In recs
                If rec.Range = p.Range Then
                    Exit For 'Stop
                End If
            Next rec
            Set lns = rec.Lines
            If lns.Count > 1 Then
                Set ln = lns(lns.Count)
                .ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=CentimetersToPoints(0.75), Alignment:=wdAlignTabCenter
                .Document.Range(lns(lns.Count).Range.Characters(1).Start, lns(lns.Count).Range.Characters(1).Start).InsertAfter vbTab
                '.Document.Range(lns(lns.Count).Range.Characters(1).Start, lns(lns.Count).Range.Characters(1).Start).InsertAlignmentTab 1, 0
            End If
        End With
    Next p
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

### Original text:

[image]

### After running the code above

[image]

## 20230618 updated Fix the bug :

**When a paragraph is across the page, there is an error. Because the line above:** `Set recs = .Document.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)).Rectangles`

```vb
Sub New_paragraph_alignment_style_Aligned_to_both_sides_and_the_last_to_the_center()
    Dim p As paragraph, ur As UndoRecord, lns As Lines, ln As Line, recs As Rectangles, rec As Rectangle
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "New_paragraph_alignment_style_Aligned_to_both_sides_and_the_last_to_the_center"
    For Each p In Selection.Paragraphs
        'Set p = Selection.Paragraphs(1)
        With p.Range
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphDistribute
            Set recs = .Document.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)).Rectangles
            For Each rec In recs
                If rec.Range = p.Range Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next rec
            
            Rem When a paragraph is across the page, there is an error. Because the line above: Set recs = .Document.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)).Rectangles
            If rec Is Nothing Then
                Set lns = recs(1).Lines
            Else
                Set lns = rec.Lines
            End If
            If lns.Count > 1 Or rec Is Nothing Then
                Set ln = lns(lns.Count)
                .ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=CentimetersToPoints(0.75), Alignment:=wdAlignTabCenter
                Rem However, please NOTE: Insert a VBTab character will inevitably affect the results of finding content text
                .Document.Range(lns(lns.Count).Range.Characters(1).Start, lns(lns.Count).Range.Characters(1).Start).InsertAfter vbTab
                '.Document.Range(lns(lns.Count).Range.Characters(1).Start, lns(lns.Count).Range.Characters(1).Start).InsertAlignmentTab 1, 0
            End If

        End With
    Next p
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reference, I didn't know that, but that's not what I asked for.
The idea you brought fits perfectly to all lines except the last one. I will build a macro that will separate the last line from the paragraph, set it as an independent paragraph. Visually, you need to set paragraph spacing before / after such that the two paragraphs look like one paragraph. The last paragraph (ie the last line) will be a centered paragraph, and the main paragraph will get the alignment you suggested.
That's what I want:
xzxzxzxzxzxzx
cxcxcxcxcxcxj
x z x z j z x z x
      ttttuhgf
Thanx!

Comment: @mordechaiasher Can you capture a screenshot so I can see how you want it to look like? Especially the last paragraph.

Comment: @mordechaiasher Fix the bug **When a paragraph is across the page, there is an error. Because the line above:** `Set recs = .Document.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)).Rectangles`